# folder access without Ethernet connection

Tags: windows-7, networking, file-transfer

I am currently working a project that requires one computer to transfer data to another computer. However, due to security policy, they are not allowed to be on the same physical network (i.e no ethernet connection). The connection need to be fairly fast ( > 5mb/s) and always active.

I have tried using a USB transfer cable, but they lack the ability to do so automatically (requires a 3rd party software with human input). The two computer are running windows 7 and fairly close to each other ( ~2ft or 60cm). What would you suggest as an alternative to ethernet (which will violate the policy)?

Comment: Would connecting over ethernet directly (crossover) violate the policy? It is a LAN technically but with no connection to other computers...

Comment: @Joshua Yes, It would, since one computer would be connected to a secure network, which requires all computer on it to satisfied some security req. However, the second computer does not have that, so they cannot be on a the same LAN.